# SELECT two columns with CASE WHEN

Tags: postgresql, case, union

I want to select three columns (id_produkt, 313, 314) so I tried:

```
select id_produkt, 
 case when bp_stan_produkt.id_stan_produkt = 313
 then 'TAK'
 else 'NIE' 
 end as "313"
 from bp_stan_produkt where data_do is not null

 union 

 select id_produkt, 
 case when bp_stan_produkt.id_stan_produkt = 314
 then 'TAK'
 else 'NIE'
 end as "314"
 from bp_stan_produkt where data_do is not null
```

but it return just two columns: id_produkt and 313.
How can I get three columns with aliases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this SQL code

```
select id_produkt, 
case when id_stan_produkt = 313 then 'TAK' 
else 'NIE'
end  as "313",
case when id_stan_produkt = 314 then 'TAK' 
else 'NIE'
end  as "314"
 from bp_stan_produkt where data_do is null
```